# PHP execute one insert SQL but add two records in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I used PHP Codeigniter's insert method to input on log data, but get two exactly same records in Mysql database. My code is like below:

```
public function add_practise_log($user_id, $question_id, $selected, $is_correct)
{
    $log_data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id, 'question_id' => $question_id, 'selected' => $selected,
        'is_correct' => $is_correct, 'practise_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );

    $this->db_write->insert(TABLE_QUESTION_PRACTISE_LOG, $log_data);

    return;
}`
```

I ensure this code was just executed only once, but in `Mysql` general log  I found two same insert queries:

```
4198 Query INSERT INTO question_practise_log 
(user_id, question_id, selected, is_correct, practise_time)
 VALUES ('20037', 6, 'option_c', 0, '2015-08-19 18:26:19')

4198 Query INSERT INTO question_practise_log 
(user_id, question_id, selected, is_correct, practise_time)
 VALUES ('20037', 6, 'option_c', 0, '2015-08-19 18:26:19')`
```

`4198` is connection id, I was so confused about this mysql activity.

Had anybody encountered this situation or can someone explain this weird action.

BTW, there also have some other methods to insert records but this situation only happened on this table

Comment: Where is your controller code?? What is this `$this->db_write`??

Comment: It seems to have something to do with your method calling. Where and how it is called?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with method calling,I  debug step by step and  var_dump `$this->db_write->queries` which contains all executed queries in a http request, there just have one query about which I mentioned above in it.  `$this->db_write` is  connection obj just as same as `$this->db` in `Codeiginter`

Comment: did you try  $this->db_write->insert('question_practise_log', $log_data); ?

Answer (score 0):

Better write this 
$this->db->insert('question_practise_log',$log_data);

Comment: `TABLE_QUESTION_PRACTISE_LOG` is a constant of `question_practise_log`.  Are they different in insert calling?

Comment: Can you show me your controller and view page so that i can help u